# Java - Treat data from a file

Tags: java

I have a file that looks like this:

```
year        population
1952        120323
1953        136688
1954        161681
....        .....
```

I want to go in that find the year with the largest increase in population as compared to the previous year.

I tried th following code but I get a the `NoSuchElementException` and I'm not sure why:

```
    String path = "filePath";
    File file = new File(filePath);
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
    int y = 0, y1, y2, p1, p2, diff = 0;
    while(sc.hasNext()){
        if(sc.next().equals("year") || sc.next().equals("population")){
            break;
        }else{
            y1 = Integer.parseInt(sc.next());
            p1 = Integer.parseInt(sc.next());
            y2 = Integer.parseInt(sc.next()); // this line throws the exception
            p2 = Integer.parseInt(sc.next());
            if(p2 - p1 > diff){
                diff = y2-y1;
                y = y2;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(y);
```

Comment: Every time that you are doing `sc.next` you are actually reading a value, so if the case of `if(sc.next().` you are reducing the availability of one token.  IMHO a better way would be to loop using `nextLine` and then splitting the values and **then** checking their values

Comment: And the `break` should be `continue`. And `Integer.parseInt(sc.next())` should be simply `sc.nextInt()`. And `nextInt()` should never be called without a prior `hasNextInt()` test. And you can do without line-splitting, but you have to consume the newline with `nextLine()` in the place where it is expected, i.e. after the first two tokens are read.

Comment: 1.366.887 is not an integer. 1366887 is an integer. Google "How to parse number string containing commas into an integer in java?" Splitting by lines is a good idea. Then read line as two strings: year, and population, before converting the strings to integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how your code produced NoSuchElementException error. Because you are exiting from the loop when you find "year" or "population". Hope the following code should meet your expected result.

```
    String path = "filePath";
    File file = new File (path);
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
    Long[][] yd = new Long[0][];
    long prev = 0;
    for(scanner.nextLine();scanner.hasNext();){
        long year = scanner.nextLong();
        long curnt = scanner.nextLong();
        long diff = prev==0?prev:curnt-prev;
        prev = curnt;
        yd = Arrays.copyOf(yd, yd.length+1);
        yd[yd.length-1] = new Long[2];
        yd[yd.length-1][0] = year;
        yd[yd.length-1][1] = diff;
    }
    Arrays.sort(yd, new Comparator<Long[]>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Long[] o1, Long[] o2) {
            Long diffOne = o1[1];
            Long diffTwo = o2[1];
            return diffTwo.compareTo(diffOne);
        }
    });
    System.out.println("Year="+yd[0][0]+"; Difference="+yd[0][1]);
```

Comment: This is working, I'm studying what you did to understand my mistakes, thanks man

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
String path = "filePath";
File file = new File (filePath);
Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
long year = 0L, population = 0L, largestDiff = 0L;

while (sc.hasNext()) {
    String line = sc.nextLine();

    if (line.startsWith("year")) {
        continue;
    } else {
        String[] parts = line.split(" +"); // Note the space before "+"
        long currentYear = Long.parseLong(parts[0]);
        long currentPopulation = Long.parseLong(parts[1]);
        long diff = currentPopulation - population;

        if (dif > largestDiff) {
            largestDiff = diff;
            year = currentYear;
        }

        population = currentPopulation;
    }
}

System.out.println(year);
System.out.println(largestDiff);
```

Comment: The programs works but it returns wrong values, like I get 329366 and 455788, there no year equals to 329366.

Comment: That's strange... Try replacing the `long` with `int`, and also `parseLong` with `parseInt`

Comment: I think `population = currentPopulation` will be out of the `if` condition. Because you need to update previous population each time.

Comment: I did both things, but getting the same results, really strange

Comment: Could u try logging the `line` variable (Currently not with my machine)...??

Comment: My apologies @KwameOpareAsiedu, I was using the wrong file, now that I got the correct file, it is giving me NumberFormatException when trying to to parse the line in currentYear. Probably because of the split line, line = 1950 2,557,628,654. Working on it..